# Pagination for Nested Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination, accordion

I am creating a Data Table but Accordion with Search and Pagination. I found this code that perfectly suits what I have in mind but the body or content of the accordion from the previous page is left even when clicked next page plus it also has lines. this will be a big problem for UX because I will be adding over 400 sets of data inside of it. please how can I hide or remove this? thanks

```
[here's the code][https://codepen.io/odettedfszdczdxc/pen/RwpjbBG]
```

Comment: Please share screenshot and then explain what you want in it so we have clear idea what your want to achive

Comment: oh sorry, I think the link for CodePen isn't showing